# All possibilities of an array list that contain LAT-LNG objects

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap

I have a list of LATLNG objects passed to a class that looks like this when I printed `[lat/lng: (1.1111,-1.8812807), lat/lng: (1.1111,-1.2000)]`
This represents two different locations in this case ( but may contain up to 8) aswell as having a current location variable within this class that has the users current location. To find the fastest path between users current location and the other two destinations i need to be able to build some sort of list or data structure that contains all the different permutations. For example, A (users current location) -> B ->C and also A-(users current location)->C->B for this example. I would then query the distance metrics api to pull back the value for seconds and add up for each comparison to see the combination with shortest time.
I am currently unsure how i should build this in order to test all the different distances. Is a list the best way or would a hashmap be suited for me to build all permatations? Any guidance to how I should go about this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a Graph.  There's an entire field of CS that studies graphs and famous algorithms for determining shortest path, I'd google graph theory and start readying.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan , I don't exactly need the shortest path as  I am able to return the time taken through an API call as i am looking for the "fastest path", its just a matter of storing the data in all its different orders ? Will a graph achieve this?